# xsl:if check that ID is not Inside Array

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to check if an id is inside an array. If it is not, then i want to add an element into the data. If the ID is in the array, i want to do nothing.

Variable name="blacklistIDs"

```
<element>1111</element>
<element>2222</element>
```

The funktion is then:

```
<xsl:if test="@ID!=$blacklistIDs/element">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
```

The check if the ID is inside the array works, however the check if ID is not inside Array does not.

Eg. Check if ID is inside the array works fine.

```
<xsl:if test="@ID=$blacklistIDs/element">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
```

What am i missing here? Is the != not funktional at this point?

Answer (score 1):

The check `@ID!=$blacklistIDs/element` will return true if `@ID` is not-equal to any of the elements in the array. That is to say, if it doesn't match at least one element, then it is true. It does not need to be different to all of them.

Change the test to this (i.e. a negation of your other logic)

```
<xsl:if test="not(@ID = blacklistIDs/element)">
```

You can read about the logic here at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#node-sets

> If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a string,
>   then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the
>   node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the
>   string-value of the node and the other string is true